# ibooks aren't syncing across iPhone and iPad

Tags: icloud, data-synchronization, books

I have downloaded ibooks from App store which sync without a problem
I have also download ibooks from the internet, but for each device I have to manually download them and also I lose all my previous bookmarks and notes.

- In `Settings .. iBooks .. sync bookmarks and Notes` is selected
- In `Settings .. iBooks .. sync collections` is selected

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to do something for iCloud Or this not doable at all.

Comment: Try this: log out of iCloud on your iPhone and reboot the device. Log in again and enable the sync. Do the same for the iPad. Please let me know if this solved the issue.

Comment: I do have other devices as well, my mac, another business iPad all using the same Apple ID. for it to work just between these 2, do I need to do this for them all. Or doing on these two would at least fix these 2 ?

Comment: Just for the devices that don't sync iBooks content.

Comment: @oa- Ummm. ooops. I wasn't logged on iCloud. I was only logged into AppStore. Sorry for the confusion. The reason I did that was because I don't want all my WhatsApp and Facebook and other apps to be available on my business iPad. So what should I do